# How to get proper linting from commandline for vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

Have searched far and wide and found numerous articles, videos etc. tangent to what I look for, but never a perfect solution.

My main question is how to get proper linting (like the one that's inbuilt and enabled by default in vscode)?

The reason is to be able to enforce this in a continuous integration setting, for example a github action rule for pull requests.

Example when using vscode default tslint:

```
export class Foo {
readonly bar: string;

constructor(bar : string) {
  this.bar123 = bar; <-- Property 'bar123 ' does not exist on type 'Foo'. Did you mean 'bar'?ts(2551)
}
```

This is excellent! Exactly what I want to include as a linting rule in the project. So I take control by disabling vscode tslint (which is deprecated now anyway?) and replace it with eslint with all the proper packages, parser options, extends and other settings.

Now it's silent! No notification about unused properties. And several other problems too are silent.

Eslint is however working and can also easily be enabled to auto-format code on save. So I am halfway there, but how to get the same quality linting? Found it strange that none of the tutorials and articles even touched on this topic.

Comment: Not that it solves your problem, but the error you are showing here is produced by `tsc` and not by `tslint`. Running `tsc` on command line should also show this error.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know what caused the error because there were no source or interactions to guide me further. Could you explain further what "tsc" is? So what I want is something like eslint that works like tsc, both in the editor (highlighter problems) and from command line.

Comment: Btw the error shown by default in vscode can be disabled with ```"typescript.validate.enable": false```.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 'tsc', the compiler gives these errors and accessible from command line too. Thanks to Tobias S leading me on the right track.